# Single word stating event date has changed

Tags: dates

I have a list of events. A few of them may be cancelled or they may be "moved" to another date. The latter are usually postponed but not necessarily.

For cancelled events I add the state "Cancelled". What is the best word (or short phrase) to describe a date change of an event? Is it "Rescheduled"?

I saw some answers here, but they referred to full sentences.

**Edit:** As it has been asked for clarification.
In the German sources usually only "verschoben" is used. In this case this can mean "date of event will be changed" but also "previous date of event has already been set to a new date". Im looking for such a word. But now I'm also thinking about introducing a new state in my data model to express the distinction between the state "to be rescheduled" and "rescheduled to/postponed to".

Comment: If the event is rescheduled at a **later date**, then you can use "Postponed".

Comment: You may need 'to be rescheduled' (which allows for cases where an alternative date has not been / may not be decided upon) as well as 'rescheduled'.

Comment: As I wrote I do not (or not always) know if the event is postponed or not. E.g. a year before a preliminary calendar is made. Later they find date collisions. So the next state is "date changed/rescheduled" but the new date is not yet known.
Edit (@Edwin): You're right. Actually the next state is not "reschedule" but "to be rescheduled". But as I'm just collecting events of others The information may not be that accurate.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. 'Postponed' need not imply a new date has been or will be set, as witnesses the common "postponed indefinitely" phrasing, which specifies a new date *has not* been set, but that a date *may or may not* be set at some future time.

Comment: I added a clarification to the initial question.

Comment: I think "postponed" implies that a new date hasn't been decided yet.  "rescheduled" is better if you're just changing the date.

Answer (score 2):

I think it also depends if there is a new date chosen already. If so you can use Rescheduled and add the new date. Otherwise you can use words like adjourned, suspended or postponed.

Comment: It's interesting to see how a discussion about wording and meaning reveals a flaw in the programmatic data model. In the usually German sources only the word "verschoben" (= "date changed" in this case) is used. And it's used for the state before AND after a new date is set.